# Azure pipeline for Maven error Unknown lifecycle phase "Dmaven.repo.local

Tags: maven, azure-devops, yaml, mule

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>clx-salesforceupsert-ifa</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>mule-application</packaging>

    <name>clx-salesforceupsert-ifa</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

        <app.runtime>4.4.0-20220221</app.runtime>
        <mule.maven.plugin.version>3.5.4</mule.maven.plugin.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.mule.tools.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>mule-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${mule.maven.plugin.version}</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                <cloudHubDeployment>
                <uri>https://anypoint.mulesoft.com</uri>
                <server>${server}</server>
                <muleVersion>${app.runtime}</muleVersion>
                <applicationName>${app.name}</applicationName>
                <workers>${workers}</workers>
                <workerType>${workerType}</workerType>
                <environment>${environment}</environment>
                <objectStoreV2>true</objectStoreV2>
                
                </cloudHubDeployment>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>deploy</id>
                        <phase>deploy</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>deploy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <classifier>mule-application</classifier>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.connectors</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-http-connector</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>
            <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.connectors</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-sockets-connector</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
            <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>anypoint-exchange-v3</id>
            <name>Anypoint Exchange</name>
            <url>https://maven.anypoint.mulesoft.com/api/v3/maven</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>mulesoft-releases</id>
            <name>MuleSoft Releases Repository</name>
            <url>https://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>mulesoft-releases</id>
            <name>MuleSoft Releases Repository</name>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <url>https://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

above is the pom.xml while trying to run azure pipeline for mule application

below is the azure-pipelines.yaml

```html
# Starter pipeline
# Start with a minimal pipeline that you can customize to build and deploy your code.
# Add steps that build, run tests, deploy, and more:
# https://aka.ms/yaml

trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest
variables:
- group: Build-Variable-Group
- name: MAVEN_CACHE_FOLDER
  value: $(pipeline.workspace)/.m2/repository
- name: MAVEN_OPTS
  value: 'Dmaven.repo.local=$(MAVEN_CACHE_FOLDER)'


steps:

- task: Cache@1
  inputs:
    key: pom.xml
    path: $(MAVEN_CACHE_FOLDER)
  displayName: Cache Maven Repo

- task: DownloadSecureFile@1
  name: settingsxml
  inputs:
    secureFile: 'settings.xml'

- task: Powershell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
        New-Item -Type Directory -Force "${HOME}/.m2"
        Copy-Item -Force "$(settingsxml.secureFilePath)" "${HOME}/.m2/settings.xml"
        
        

- task: Maven@3
  inputs:
    mavenPomFile: 'pom.xml'
    mavenOptions: '-Xmx3072m'
    jdkVersionOption: '17.0.3'
    jdkArchitectureOption: 'x64'
    mavenAuthenticateFeed: true
    publishJUnitResults: false
    javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
    mavenVersionOption: 'Default'
    effectivePomSkip: true
    goals: 'clean install package deploy $(MAVEN_OPTS) -DmuleDeploy -Dserver=$(server) Denvironment=$(environment) -Dworkers=$(workers) -DworkerType=$(workerType) -Dapp.runtime=$(app.runtime) -Dapp.name=$(app.name)'
  
  
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    ArtifactName: 'drop'
    publishLocation: 'Container'
- task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
  inputs:
    targetPath: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)'
    publishLocation: 'pipeline'
```

but while running getting the below error

```
[ERROR] Unknown lifecycle phase "Dmaven.repo.local=/home/vsts/work/1/.m2/repository". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy. -> [Help 1]
```

Comment: First: `'Dmaven.repo.local=$(MAVEN_CACHE_FOLDER)'` there is missing a prefixing `-`... second which. Maven do you use? This: `clean install package deploy` is simply wrong.. use only `clean deploy` ... instead... why do you need so much memory `-Xmx3072m`? This: ` Denvironment=$(environment)` is wrong as well. There must be `-` in fron of the `D..`....

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but, 1) I have added '-' before Denvironment, change the command from clean install package deploy to clean deploy but no luck, same error appearing

Comment: Then the commands in your pipeline definition are wrongly separated etc.

Comment: Please accept the answer if useful to signal that it is valid to other users with a similar issue. You can also upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use the goals configuration to put the Java options for Maven (ie mavenOpts). Just specify the goals there like `package`. There are other configurations to set Maven command line options like `mavenOptions` which the script already has. Also, does $(MAVEN_OPTS) actually has something that you need to pass to Maven? It maybe better to just put it explicitly in `mavenOptions` to have more repeatable builds.

However after rereading the error it is just that the definition of variable `MAVEN_OPTS` is missing the minus character before the 'D'. It should be:

```
 value: '-Dmaven.repo.local=$(MAVEN_CACHE_FOLDER)'
```

It is a syntax error in configuring the Azure pipeline for the Maven task, unrelated to the Mule project.